# How to display just the child menu items in appfuse

Tags: java, jsp, appfuse

(I think this is coming from appfuse, anyway. I'm not always clear on what's part of which framework still.)

I've got this in my `menu-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MenuConfig>
    <Displayers>
        <Displayer name="Velocity" type="net.sf.navigator.displayer.VelocityMenuDisplayer"/>
    </Displayers>
    <Menus>
        <Menu name="MainMenu" title="mainMenu.title" page="/mainmenu">
            <Item name="Foo" title="menu.foo" page="/foo"/>
            <Item name="Bar" title="menu.bar" page="/bar"/>
            <Item name="Baz" title="menu.baz" page="/baz"/>
        </Menu>
        <Menu name="OtherMenu" title="otherMenu.title" page="/othermenu">
            <Item name="Squee" title="menu.squee" page="/squee"/>
            <Item name="Lorem" title="menu.lorem" page="/lorem"/>
        </Menu>
        <Menu name="UserMenu" title="menu.user" description="User Menu" page="mainmenu.editprofile" roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <Menu name="Logout" title="user.logout" page="/logout" roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    </Menus>
</MenuConfig>
```

For my main navigation, I've got this in my menu.jsp:

```
<%@ include file="/common/taglibs.jsp"%>

<menu:useMenuDisplayer name="Velocity" config="cssHorizontalMenu.vm" permissions="rolesAdapter">
<ul class="tabs menuList">
    <menu:displayMenu name="MainMenu"/>
</ul>
</menu:useMenuDisplayer>
```

That pretty much works, except I'm getting both the top level and child items of the main menu in my output. I actually only want the child items, i.e.:

```
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Baz</li>
</ul>
```

not

```
<ul>
   <li>Main Menu</li>
   <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Baz</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

So late, but I hope can help to somebody...

Do you need look into your cssHorizontalMenu.vm, it does the work of generation of the HTML output. If do you have a .vm

Maybe you have something like this:

```
#macro( displayCssMenu $menu )
  #if ($displayer.isAllowed($menu))
    #set ($count = $count + 1)
    ## set menu title
    #set ($title = $displayer.getMessage($menu.title))
    #if (!$menu.url) #set ($url="javascript:void(0)") #else #set ($url=$menu.url) #end

    ## create a single menu item
    #set ($itemClass = "")
    #if (!$menu.parent)
        #set ($itemClass = "mainItem")
    #end
    #set ($img = "")
    #if ($menu.image)
        #set ($img = "<img alt='$menu.image' class='icon setImageMenu $menu.image'/>")
    #end
    #if ($menu.components.size() == 0)
        #if ($count == $renderedChildren)
          <li class="last">
        #else
          <li>
        #end
        #if ($menu.name == $currentMenu)
          <a href="$url" title="$title" class="current $itemClass" #if($menu.target)target="$menu.target" #end#if($menu.width)style="width: ${menu.width}px"#end>$img ${title}</a>
        #else
          <a href="$url" title="$title" class="$itemClass" #if($menu.target)target="$menu.target" #end#if($menu.width)style="width: ${menu.width}px"#end>$img ${title}</a>
        #end
    #else ## create multiple menu items in a menu
        #if ($menu.components.size() > 0)
            #set ($hasViewableChildren = false)
            #set ($renderedChildren = 0)
            #foreach ($menuIt in $menu.components)
                #if ($displayer.isAllowed($menuIt))
                    #set($hasViewableChildren = true)
                    #set($renderedChildren = $renderedChildren + 1)
                #end
            #end
        #end

        <li#if ($hasViewableChildren) class="menubar"#end>
          <a href="$url" title="$title" #if ($menu.name == $currentMenu) class="current $itemClass" #else class="$itemClass" #end#if($menu.target)target="$menu.target" #end#if($menu.width)style="width: ${menu.width}px"#end>$img ${title}</a>
    #end

    #if ($menu.components.size() > 0)
        #if ($hasViewableChildren) 
          <ul> 
        #end

        #set ($count = 0)
        #foreach ($menuIt in $menu.components)
            #displayCssMenu($menuIt)
        #end

        #if ($hasViewableChildren && ($count == $renderedChildren))
          </li>
        #else
          </ul>
          #if ($count > $renderedChildren) 
          </li>
          #end
        #end
    #else
      </li>
      #if ($count == $menu.parent.components.size())
      </ul>
      #end
    #end
  #end
#end

#displayCssMenu($menu)
```

then you can try to do this... (look for the **#if ($menu.parent)**)

```
#if ($menu.components.size() == 0 && $menu.parent)
        #if ($count == $renderedChildren)
          <li class="last">
        #else
          <li>
        #end
        bla.. bla...

        bla.. bla...
    #end

    #if ($menu.components.size() > 0)
        #if ($hasViewableChildren) 
          <ul> 
        #end

        bla.. bla...
    #else
        #if ($menu.parent)
             </li>
        #end
      #if ($count == $menu.parent.components.size())
          </ul>
      #end
    #end
```

this prevent to print the LI A elements for the parent menu, and only prints the items elements...